# Functions that call each other, declared inside another function

Tags: c, function, recursion

I have two functions that call each other, inside of another function:

```
int main(){
    void aaa();

    void b(){
        aaa();
    }

    void aaa(){
        b();
    }

    aaa();
}
```

(Yes, this example would be stuck in an infinite loop or cause a stack overflow)

The compiler throws the error: `static declaration of 'aaa' follows non-static declaration`

If I move the function declarations outside of the other function, it works (but I can't do that because those functions need to have access to `main`'s local variables)

Is it possible to make this work?

Comment: You can't nest function definitions  in Standard C. GNU C only supports it as an extension.

Comment: Why don't you just declare these functions outside the main as it should be, and then pass the main variables you need inside these functions as parameters?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that wasn't part of the standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C does not support nested functions, nor closures.

One solution for your actual problem is to define the shared state (the local variables of main you mentioned, in this case) as struct, then have variable of this struct type, and pass it as pointer to the functions that use it.

You don't show the local variable code in your question, so I'm not writing and arbitrary example. Please edit the question with more code, if you want an example.

---

Another solution is to just use global (preferably static) variables, used both from other functions and main. I mean, since main isn't a normal function (can't be called recursively by standard, for example), its local variables end up being unique objects anyway, so this is just a matter of scope and visibility, with little to no funcional difference.